# Is there a way to use Z3 to get models for constraints involving sets?

Tags: set, z3

I am trying to model sets in Z3 such that I am able to find models to
constraints involving sets.

I currently represent a set using an array. An element belongs to the set
if the corresponding entry in the array is true. I then have some axioms
which I use in constraints.

Here is an example in SMT 2.0.

```
(define-sort Set (T) (Array T Bool))

(declare-fun |Set#Card| ((Set Int)) Int)
(assert (forall ((s (Set Int)))
      (!
        (<= 0 (|Set#Card| s))
          :pattern ((|Set#Card| s)))))

(declare-fun |Set#Singleton| (Int) (Set Int))
(assert (forall ((r Int))
      (!
        (select (|Set#Singleton| r) r)
       :pattern ((|Set#Singleton| r)))))
(assert (forall ((r Int) (o Int))
      (iff (select (|Set#Singleton| r) o) (= r o))))
(assert (forall ((r Int)) (= (|Set#Card| (|Set#Singleton| r)) 1)))

(declare-fun s () (Set Int))
(assert (= 1 (|Set#Card| s)))
;(assert (= 1 (|Set#Card| (|Set#Singleton| 1))))
;(assert (not (= 1 (|Set#Card| (|Set#Singleton| 1)))))
(check-sat)
(get-info :reason-unknown)
(get-model)
```

My problem is that I get `unknown` and therefore no model for most cases.
I think my axiomatization is too weak. In the example above I would
like to get a model for a set `s` which contains one element.

**Does anyone know how I could use Z3 to get models for constraints
involving sets?**

Every answer is helpful. I.e., perhaps I misunderstand what Z3 can
and cannot do. Ideas on how I could deal with this problem are welcome
too (other tool suggestions, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Z3 will fail to build a model that satisfies assertions such as:

```
(assert (forall ((r Int) (o Int))
      (iff (select (|Set#Singleton| r) o) (= r o))))
```

One possible workaround is to define `|Set#Singleton|` instead of axiomatizing it.
We can define it using the `const` array operator, and `store`. Here is a possible definition:

```
(define-fun |Set#Singleton| ((r Int)) (Set Int)
            (store ((as const (Set Int)) false) r true))
```

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Dfs1) is a link for your modified example with this definition. Z3 returns `sat` and a model after I use the definition.

In the textual interface, we have to use `as` construct to specify the kind of constant array we want.
Note that, we can encode several set operations using the extended array theory available in Z3. [This paper](http://leodemoura.github.io/files/fmcad09.pdf) has additional details. However, this approach can't encode the `|Set#Card|` function.

Another option is to use "candidate models" for `unknown` results. This is not the ideal solution, but several users do that.

Comment: Thank you. I tried "candidate models" but they are not accurate a lot of times. Later on I would also need to support set equality, intersection, disjointness and so on. Do you know of an approach which works for these cases?

Comment: The extended array theory (described in the paper I cited) can be used  to encode set equality, intersection, etc. Cardinality is the main operation that can't be encoded.

Comment: The Z3 tutorial has an example (http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide). See section: Mapping Functions on Arrays

Comment: I'm now trying to use the .NET API (`MkMap`) for this. Are the boolean functions predefined or do I need to define them myself?

Comment: I use now uninterpreted functions and assert it as required by the particular boolean function.